# What does PCI bus 0, device 2, function 0 in Intel HD Graphic properties mean?

Tags: laptop, drivers, intel-graphics

I bought new laptop and explore on device manager (Windows 10) What is it mean.

[image: intel HD Graphics properties]

Answer (score 1):

It is not "properties", it is your video card topological location in terms of PCI: bus/device/functuion.

You have PCI Express bus whose controller (aka "Root Complex") is built directly into your CPU. Integrated GPU is also there. All other PCI-Express devices (like your 802.11(wifi) adapter) are also on this bus although they are not built-it like GPU.

On each boot Windows pnp manager (subsystem running in kernel space) builds device tree. It uses ACPI tables provided by motherboard firmware to find Root Complex and some built-in devices. It then asks Root Complex to list all devices it has, and finally creates device tree.

On PCI and PCI express each device has unique topological address.

1) Bus: There could be several buses connected to first pci bus using bridge: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#/media/File:Example_PCI_Express_Topology.svg

Your device is connected to bus0 (first bus).

2) Device (physical): There can be several devices on bus, Video adapter is device number 2.

3) Function (logical device) Each device may host several functions: Sound card may have PCM and MIDI, multi-card may have several serial ports etc. This is function number 0 (first function)

Answer (score -3):

These are the slots in the computer:

[image]

If you want to read further on PCI, some useful info: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/pci.htm

Intel HD Graphics are generally integrated into the CPU itself, so it is probably why it says that also

Comment: These are the slots in the computer: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pci+computer&biw=1920&bih=955&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0uaShtsLRAhVlLsAKHYouAEsQ_AUIBygC#imgrc=_sHd4s2Zj79gBM%3A Some useful info: http://computer.howstuffworks.com/pci.htm